# Is there any Java API to generate xml at runtime with the input xml schema and key value pair of xpath expressions and data

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have the xml schema file at runtime which is changeable. I am getting the java Collection in my code with XPath expressions and the value to be entered in the XML file. With the help of all these runtime inputs I have to generate the XML file. 
    Attached below are sample input and output.

1. Below is example schema( No fixed format ):

   ```
       <xs:complexType name="root">
           <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element name="top" type="topType" />
           </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>            
      <xs:element name="root" type="root">
      </xs:element>              
      <xs:complexType name="topType">
         <xs:element name="mode" use="required" />
          <xs:element name="address" use="required" />
      </xs:complexType>
   ```
2. The xpath Expression & value I m getting is in key value pair from Hash Map. I need these xpath values to be placed with the corresponding XMLElement value in output.xml. The xpath expressions and values are as follows :

   1. Expression: /root/top/address Value:10.200.111.
   2. Expression: /root/top/mode Value:cluster
3. The java code should generate the XML file as Output.xml :(This is the dummy file which needs to be generated at runtime from all collected inputs)

   ```
   <root>
       <top>
           <mode>cluster</mode>
           <address>10.200.111.111</address>
       </top>
   </root>
   ```

Please suggest if anyone have came across such scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/)

Comment: @Craig, I am having the basic understanding of JAXB. Could you please be bit specific which areas I should look probably. This will be of really help.

Comment: Work through [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JAXB/article.html), it will give you a good understanding of how to map java classes (POJO's) to xml files and back again. Lars Vogel is a good resource

Comment: JAXB would be _it_, if the problem was not so fixed. XSLT could do it partially. But a straight Java application that takes the xsd and does difficult things probably is unavoidable.

Comment: For JAXB we need either the xml file for unmarshalling the xml data to object or the java Object with all data members set with appropriate values to be produced as xml file (marshalling). But my concern is neither side is directly available to me. So is there any third party tool that takes the runtime generated classes from xsd to set the class parameters with provided xpaths-data value key pair and marshal that object to xml?

Answer (score 1):

Please check out this below code to generate xml from xsd once generated use XMLDocument, XPath to Update/add fields

```
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import jlibs.xml.sax.XMLDocument;
import jlibs.xml.xsd.XSInstance;
import jlibs.xml.xsd.XSParser;

import org.apache.xerces.xs.XSModel;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class XSDToXML {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws ClassCastException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InstantiationException
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,
            InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassCastException {
        try {

            XSModel model = (XSModel) new XSParser().parse("c:\\kar\\xs.xsd");
            XMLDocument sample = new XMLDocument(new StreamResult(
                "c:\\kar\\root3.xml"), false, 4, null);
                        QName root = new QName("root");
            XSInstance instance = new XSInstance();
            instance.minimumElementsGenerated = 0;
            instance.maximumElementsGenerated = 0;
            instance.generateDefaultAttributes = true;
            instance.generateOptionalAttributes = true;
            instance.maximumRecursionDepth = 0;
            instance.generateOptionalElements = true;
            instance.generate(model, root, sample);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

U need to download jlibs-xml.jar , xercesImpl.jar and jlibs-core.jar files

Answer (score 0):

Just check out this code its pretty simple

```
public class MyTestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
        Map map= new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("cluster", "10.200.111.111");
        map.put("cluster1", "10.200.121.111");

        MyXML xml = new MyXML();
        List<Top> top1= new ArrayList<Top>();
        Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
        for(String key : keys){
            Top top=new Top();
            top.setMode(key);
            top.setAddress((String)map.get(key));
            top1.add(top);
        }
        xml.setTop(top1);
        File file = new File("C:\\kar\\file.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyXML.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        // output pretty printed
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(xml, file);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(xml, System.out);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}


@XmlRootElement(name="top")
@XmlType(name="top")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Top {

    @XmlElement(name="mode", required=true)
    private String mode;

    @XmlElement(name="mode", required=true)
    private String address;

    public String getMode() {
        return mode;
    }

    public void setMode(String mode) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }




}





@XmlRootElement(name="root")
@XmlType(name="root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyXML {


    @XmlElement(name="Top")
    private List<Top> top;

    public List<Top> getTop() {
        return top;
    }

    public void setTop(List<Top> top) {
        this.top = top;
    }

}
```

You can even do it using XSLT, http://www.ictforu.com/index.php/Core-Java/java-xslt.html

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. I am aware of JAXB marshal/ unmarshal with defined pojo classes. But in my case I am getting every time new xml schema format at runtime as I mentioned above.